# How do you build large complex application in python with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How do you build complex application, I mean application with lots of code in kivy. Like a game that has many levels when you can't import one kivy file inside another(not .kv)

Comment: You should write "lots of code", then do "lots of tests" until it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Screen Manager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) for create pages so you can transfer values between these screens.It doesn't matter how many screen u created or you wrote code.You can create your own game which has different levels or characters (and other things.) I'm seeing you asking many questions in these days.But you're asking another question before giving any feedback or confirmation. Y**ou have to start coding first**, after that you can share your issues here with an examples. Start coding for you game. So we can help you.